# How to see result of Flux<Object> in Postman?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I mimic tutorial at https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/spring-webflux-tutorial/ . My MongoDB (My version https://fastdl.mongodb.org/windows/mongodb-windows-x86_64-5.0.5-signed.msi). Postman v9.8.0 , Windows 10 x64.

[image]

My controller

```java
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.Employee;
import com.howtodoinjava.demo.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/create", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public void create(@RequestBody Employee e) {
        employeeService.create(e);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<Employee>> findById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Mono<Employee> e = employeeService.findById(id);
        HttpStatus status = e != null ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        return new ResponseEntity<Mono<Employee>>(e, status);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Flux<Employee> findByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return employeeService.findByName(name);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Flux<Employee> findAll() {
        // Flux<Employee> emps = employeeService.findAll();
        Flux<Employee> emps = employeeService.findAll().log().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

        emps.subscribe();

        return emps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Mono<Employee> update(@RequestBody Employee e) {
        return employeeService.update(e);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        employeeService.delete(id).subscribe();
    }

}
```

In debug console, I see the result

[image]

[image]

Comment: `emps.subscribe();` - why?

Comment: I am new to Spring Reactive, I don't know about this, please guide me show result to PostMan. I mimic at https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/spring-webflux-tutorial/

Comment: Looks fine apart from the subscribe call, remove that. Rule out Postman first - try with `curl -N` for example.

Comment: This is my result https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/148344502-7f123771-ced4-4ac3-bb66-96a76ac01b0c.png I tried `//emps.subscribe();` stop, debug, then `curl -N http://localhost:8080`

Comment: this is my project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U3qMc1hQRUi5akm8oVmAF6it7nypSD_V/view?usp=sharing please help me

Comment: I see in tutorial used it, I just mimics. I remove it, but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the responses are empty is that no getter methods are defined in the `Employee` entity class. Adding the following should make it work:

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public long getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
```

As a side note, consider mapping your entities into `EmployeeDTO` instances.

Comment: Good catch, and so strange. Why my `get`s did not work? https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/0bcfb699fc61b90557fe1f815290691b#file-employee-java-L41-L52

Comment: Because your methods don't have the prefix `get`.